# Is it possible to use Google sheet's IMPORTXML to extract data from a website document which file format is unknown to me?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm wondering if there's a way to extract data/information from the document shown in the link below, using Google sheets' IMPORTXML?

https://app.safetyculture.com/report/public/audit/3fa14de51938e5946b0c5f276db75e217e7dba82d0a9fe4f0abf695bd1bb284e?utm_source=iauditor_android&utm_medium=export_email

I tried understanding and using XPath, but can't make it work.
I would greatly appreciate any help from someone.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The site you're trying to extract data from, loads with JavaScript and the IMPORT function can’t extract content that loads with JavaScript. You can check this [thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/111939291/issue-with-importxml?hl=en#:%7E:text=Recommended%20Answer-,Recommended,-G).

You can check that the website is JavaScript controlled by clicking on the ‘Lock’ icon beside the browser’s address bar, select ‘Site settings’ and set JavaScript to ‘Block’. Reload the page and as you can see the screenshot below, the site needs JavaScript enabled to load data.

[image]